# Why are Python's third-packages installed by default in different directory than the Python's installation on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

The Python's installation directory is `C:\Program Files\pyt` and it has a file and directory `C:\Program Files\pyt\Lib\site-packages\README.txt` stating:

> This directory exists so that 3rd party packages can be installed
> here.  Read the source for site.py for more details.

In `site.py` there's nothing specific?

On the other hand all third-party packages are installed in `C:\Users\greatuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages` e.g. boto3-1.16.60.dist-info by default.

Why aren't all the packages installed in `C:\Program Files\pyt\Lib\site-packages\` directory? What is the difference and how is the installation directory set?

Comment: AFAIK `%APPDATA%` is used when installing with the `--user` argument. Example: `pip install --user boto3` Some editors will install `pylint` with this option as sometimes `C:\Program Files\*` requires admin privileges and this ensures a UAC prompt isn't needed for installing it in say VSCode.

Comment: @Axe319 you can write it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, `pip` will install to the `%APPDATA%` directory if the `--user` option is specified.
Example:

```
pip install --user boto3
```

This is helpful when the Python installation is installed to `C:\Program Files\` and you don't have admin rights.

Some editors will install `pylint` using this option to avoid a UAC prompt.

While I personally install everything via command line it seems reasonable that other third party applications that install packages would do so as well.